# Django: html without CSS and the right text

Tags: python, html, css, django, url

First of all, this website that I'm trying to build is my first, so take it easy. Thanks. Anyway, I have my home page, **home.html**, that extends from **base.html**, and **joke.html**, that also extends **base.html**. The home page works just fine, but not the joke page. Here are some parts of my files, for you to understand how I want my system to work:

**views.py**

```
def joke_page(request, joke_id):
    joke = Joke.objects.get(id=int(joke_id))
    return render(request, 'joke.html', {'joke': joke})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home_page, name='home_page'),
    url(r'^(?P<joke_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.joke_page, name='joke_page'),
]
```

**joke.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block header_text %}{{ joke.title }}{% endblock %}

{% block text %}{{ joke.text }}{% endblock %}
```

What I want is that URLs that end like **jokes/1/** to render a page with the right html using joke.html. Instead, it renders a page without CSS or with joke.title and joke.text Also, I noticed that jokes/1/ doesn't find anything:

```
DoesNotExist at /jokes/1/

Joke matching query does not exist..
```

I had 20 jokes in the database and I can find jokes/2/ through jokes/21/, which means their ids have shifted? :P
Can someone experienced with Django point out my(many, without a doubt) mistakes? Thank you!

**Edit: second urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', jokes_views.home_page, name='home'),
    url(r'^jokes/', include(jokes_urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

Comment: None of your URL rules matches `/jokes/1`, You have the homepage `/ `and any number like `/1/`. That's all.

Comment: It seems the problem is the ID. You've probably removed and re-create objects in the DB and the ID is auto-increment, which means that you may not already have the ID that you expect. Use a tool to directly access your DB and see the ID of your objects. Also as @KlausD. says, I see in your URLs that you have not the URL `jokes/1/` but you said that you **can** find `jokes/21/`, so I will assume it is a mistake in the question.

Comment: I added the other urls.py file, it might clear some things up...

Comment: better is `^(?P<joke_id>\d+)/$`

Comment: you have imported like this, `import jokes.urls as jokes_urls`, may I assume?

Comment: Actually: from jokes import urls as jokes_urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the {% load staticfiles %} in your templates?

Comment: I never thought it would be THAT simple... Thank you and again thank you!